# Access key ID and Secret Access Key for AWS Educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Educate Account but I'm unable to get the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key for the account. It mentions that I do not have IAM access when I try to follow the AWS guide on getting these, does that mean that there's no way for me to get it using the educate account?

Comment: Could you please clarify your situation... Do you have a login to the AWS Management Console? Do you login with an email address (Root account) or via Account/Username/Password (IAM User)? What do you mean "AMI access" -- do you mean you are trying to login (SSH/RDP) to an Amazon EC2 instance? What did you want to do with the Access Key/Secret Key -- that is for API access, not for logging into an EC2 instance. Any information you can provide would help us to provide you with a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it was IAM access, not AMI. I want to use the keys to set up a vagrant box which will deploy into AWS for that I require those two keys. I can login to the AWS Management Console and I can SSH into any instance I create, I need the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, not the private key (already have this). I've logged in using an email id and password so root account.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

1) Go to [Vocareum](https://labs.vocareum.com/main). This is kinda the main page of your student AWS account.

2) Find the blue button Account Details, click it - profit!

Answer (score 8):

From vocareum main page > Account details > AWS CLI > Show
Copy and paste the CLI details into '~/.aws/credentials' for mac   and 'C:/users/%UserProfile%/.aws/credentials' for windows.

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
aws_access_key_id=*****
aws_secret_access_key=*******
aws_session_token=***********************
```

'region' is not present in AWS CLI details from Vocareum. So please don't forget to add it. You can specify any region.

If you want to verify your details add 'output = json' along with the above details in your credentials file and run the command 'aws sts get-caller-identity'.
It will display your Account ID, User ID and ARN.

To check if your CLI is working, you can try to connect to S3 bucket using
aws s3 ls

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to create a personal account and use the free tier. This is a better way for education pupose. 
AWS Educate account has limited access, you can't create users with keys, the root user can't create buckets from scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://labs.vocareum.com/ and there you will find Account details . just click on it .
2. there you will see AWS CLI . Here you will see your aws_access_key_id , aws_secret_access_key and aws_session_token .  Go to C:/users/Dell/.aws/credentials then copy and paste the line of AWS CLI to the credentials file

All done !! you will now can be able to access your SQS , S3 Bucket without Create an user in IAM . in student account , it can't be accessed to create an IAM User.

Comment: And to prove what [Zahid Ahmed said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037019/3023395), open a terminal (cmd) and type the following command: `aws sts get-caller-identity` It is very important that in addition to the keys you also copy `aws_session_token`. Which usually changes, is a tedious task every time you log in that you have to modify your credentials file but it is the only way