# AWS Educate Starter Account obtain credentials in Python with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS Educate Starter Account, and I want to be able to generate automatically my credentials (*aws_access_key_id*, *aws_secret_access_key*, *aws_session_token*) from my code.

Currently, the way I do it is:

1) Login with my university email and password in [labs.vocareum.com](http://labs.vocareum.com)

2) Click on Account Details and copy and paste the credentials into ~/.aws/credentials for AWS CLI

3) In my Python code I use boto3 to interact with s3

But I would like to do everything in my Python script, without logging in every time and copy the credentials, since they are temporary credentials (they expire every 1 hour).

The type of account doesn't allow me to create and IAM User either.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515079/access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-aws-educate-account) is a similar question, but is 2 years old and doesn't have an answer on how to do it without logging in.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

labs.vocareum manage keys for your AWS Educate. It is not possible to do this since you will be locked out before you can reschedule your session. Unfortunately, there is currently no other way but the current method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).