# Access Key and Secret Key for AWS Educate Starter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I use AWS Educate Starter for one simple Reason:

I want to UPLOAD an image from iOS to S3 and then get its URL. In order to do so I need an access key and an secret key, which I can find, as I found out here [Access key ID and Secret Access Key for AWS Educate account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515079/access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-aws-educate-account).

My Problem is:
I go to this site, click the blue button expand the details and copy the **aws_access_key_id** and **aws_secret_access_key** into my Xcode project. There I get the information, that my Access Key is invalid and after playing around a little bit I recognised, that the 2 values change all the time I'm loading the *labs.vocareum.com* site new.

What am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: Does the Access Key start with `AK` or `AS`? If it is `AK`, then this is a 'permanent' key. If it starts with `AS`, then it is generated by the Security Token Service and is only valid for a limited time period.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, these aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_id, and aws_session_token is not permanent. Every time you start a session on AWS Educate Starter Account, different credentials will be generated.

**Each session would last for few hours**, so if your program uploads images to S3 using non-permanent credentials (aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_id, aws_session_token), your program can upload without having any problem for few hours, **then afterward it would not work anymore because the session would be terminated**.

In a normal AWS account, you are able to get/create the permanent access key and whatnot from IAM. However, as you may already know, in AWS Educate Account, you cannot add/create the access key to your IAM user, because you don't have permission.

The only way to solve this problem is to create a standard non-educate AWS account or change credentials every time the session expires.

To answer your question, you are not doing anything wrong. Each session expires in few hours, so that is the reason why you are getting Access Key Invalid error.