# Cannot connect to AWS Educate with visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I need to connect to **AWS Educate** account with **C#**( visual studio). I can do it under **Standard** account but when i connect to Educate account it shows my "***invalid credentials token***,,,,,". i got Credentials for Educate account through https://labs.vocareum.com/, under ***account details*** blue button. I used the credentials inside the code same as what i did with standard account. Could you help me it is really important for me. This is my connection code:

```
rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient("A****",
                                                "n****",
                                                "session_token***"
                                                 Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
DetectLabelsResponse detectLabelsResponse = rekognitionClient.DetectLabels(detectlabelsRequest);
```

Comment: How recently did you sign up for AWS Educate? Is your Educate account still in a provisioning stage? Have you received emails requesting further identification or information?

Comment: @NickWalsh Thanks for response,I signed up in less than a week. nothing requested and it works for some permitted services. I am in contact with them, they say for example , training job for sage maker is restricted for educate account and not possible, i am afraid they do not allow us to connect by code for same reason. So ridiculous,,,,

Comment: While it's true that some services are restricted on Educate accounts, I don't think that Rekognition is one of them. Can you sign into your AWS account through the console separate from vocareum, create an admin IAM user, and try with those credentials?

Comment: @NickWalsh the only way that I am able to enter to EDUCATE account is Vocarum. I can enter to console by that and create IAM roles but CANNOT  create access keys(As it said in AWS documents) which is needed for connection by code. Thats the problem, access keys!

Comment: Does the answer provided here help you to find access keys? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515079/access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-aws-educate-account

Comment: @NickWalsh I already seen this answer, I used credential as it said but its not working, No it doesnt help yet.

Comment: @NickWalsh i found the issue, i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally  I found The issue, 
The point is for Educate Account there is a session which is changed every  around 2 hours(you can see the time in vocareum.com ). SO you have to change the credential every time session gets new and put Session token in as one of the parameters. 
Thanks @Nick. I Edited the answer

Comment: No worries, glad you were able to get the problem solved