# Problem on creating access tokens for IAMUSER via aws educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use aws s3 on my laravel project , for this i created a bucket on s3 and also created IAMUSER and give it "S3FullAccess" permission but it create user with some error, access_key not created...
I use my vocareum account credentails (found on Account details button) but laravel gives an error "Invalid access token".
please help...

[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMAfC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AWS Educate Starter Account you **can't create access keys** for IAM users. From their [docs](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf):

> You can create users, but **cannot** associate login profile or **access keys** for them

The AWS Educate accounts have a lot of limitations and they just barely allow to do what you need to do in your classrooms.

Comment: Oh! That means educational account is just a waste , not a good option for making project related work 

Comment: @Matcin offcourse your answer is acceptable, but i can't vote your answer due to insufficient reputation

Comment: @Matcin Done 

Comment: Can't you create an access token for the main account? I can confirm too IAM users are denied that specific action within the educate scope
EDIT: ok you can get an access key to use with aws cli

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the user you are logging into AWS as is not an administrator user, or certainly lacks some administration permissions.

I'm not familiar with Vocareum but it seems to be some sort of learning management system - I presume you are using an AWS account that they control, which would explain the lack of privileges.  If that is the case, and it is their AWS account that you are accessing, then you will need to raise a support case with them.

If this is your account, and you created this user, then you need to log into the account as the root user you created when you configured your AWS account and use it to create an access key for this current user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515079/access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-aws-educate-account

I found this, but it cant help me

Comment: I don't get the difference between IAM user/access token vs vocareum/awscli/access key  This is probably limited with aws cli workflows and not the whole scripting scope you can expect.