# How to check running resources in AWS Educate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-billing

I am not authorised to use the billing console; neither am I allowed to create usable IAM roles.

I am currently running a free tier EC2 micro instance, but it costs me my credits.

How do I find out about any unintentionally allocated resources?

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515079/access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-aws-educate-account/53451724#53451724) about how to log in using AWS-CLI. But it does not help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can do except to do it "manually". AWS Educate starter accounts are very limited. They only operate in **one region** (us-east-1) and support **only selected services** listed [here](https://awseducate-starter-account-services.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Educate_Starter_Account_Services_Supported.pdf).

In the **worst case scenario** you have to go to each service supported and check if you run any resources they provide. Since the starter accounts are so limited, there is actually not match to check - only one region with selected services.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF! Any idea as to where I can post my Educate based doubts? The FAQ section is also **explicitly** denied access to :(

Comment: @correaswebert You could ask your educator or AWS Educate support.